# Moment.js returning NaN in Firefox but not chrome

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following line of code:

```
moment("11-10-2013 09:03 AM").diff(moment(),"minutes");
```

In Chrome 30.0.1599.101, the following line return a number (It will change every minute so the exact value is not relevant).

In Firefox 25.0, it returns `NaN`.

I am using the moment.js 2.4.0.

Does anyone understand why this works in Chrome and not FF?  I have a feeling it has to do with the way Chrome and Firefox parse date string, but haven't been able to put my finger on the exact reason.

Comment: this is not a fault of moment.js. `Date.parse("11-10-2013 09:03 AM")` does return NaN in firefox but integer in chrome.

Comment: `Date.parse("11/10/2013 09:03 AM")` works though!

Comment: @PranavGupta You are right!  I just arrived at the same conclusion and changed the format of the dates.  If you add an answer, I will go ahead an accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Date.parse("11/10/2013 09:03 AM")` or `Date.parse("11 10 2013 09:03 AM")` seem to work in firefox. Chrome seems to be more permissible with delimiters, allowing `.`, `-`, and even `;` but what's standard it'll only be possible to tell by looking at specifications.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
console.log(moment().diff(moment("11-10-2013 09:03 AM", "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A"), "minute"));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8n6k/7/)

Comment: This is also a really good answer, especially if you are not able to control the format of the date string to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Moment takes milliseconds as a number not a string or at least the raw milliseconds as string has been deprecated. Try this

```
moment(Number("11-10-2013 09:03 AM"))
```